# What is the python3 analogue of the command % used in Mathematica?

Tags: python-3.x

I am used to coding in Matematica. I find the command % to be very useful. It basically calls the previously executed command. For example if I evaluate in a cell

```
numberlist={1,2,3,4};
%
```

I get as output

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

What is the analogue of % in python3?

Comment: in the python shell and ipython/jupyter: `_`. note that this is available in interactive shells only.

Comment: @hiro protagonist and when writing a script?

Comment: no, there is no such thing in python for that. you have to use a variable.